# How can I use ghci with my reflex project using only stack.yaml?

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, reflex

I've removed nix from my reflex project, having replaced it with stack. Everything is good, except being able to use the repl. I've tried to create a minimal reflex project to demonstrate what I have tried, and the errors my attempt produces.

https://github.com/mlitchard/reflex-todo

stack repl --stack-yaml=stack-ghc.yaml

Truncated error log

```
Error: -- While building custom Setup.hs for package jsaddle-dom 
-0.9.2.0 using: /home/mlitchard/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64- 
linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack- 
work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:jsaddle-dom --ghc- 
options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file" Process exited with code: 
ExitFailure 1 Logs have been written to:

/home/mlitchard/projects/git/reflex-todo/.stack-work/logs/jsaddle-dom-0.9.2.0.log

Preprocessing library jsaddle-dom-0.9.2.0...
[587 of 599] Compiling JSDOM.Custom.XMLHttpRequest ( 
src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64- 
linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.o )

/home/mlitchard/projects/git/reflex-todo/.stack- 
work/downloaded/Vheiln5kqwE0/src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs:39:46: 
error:
    • Could not deduce (Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow
                      Language.Javascript.JSaddle.Types.JSM)
    arising from a use of ‘throwM’
  from the context: MonadDOM m
    bound by the type signature for:
               throwXHRError :: MonadDOM m => Maybe XHRError -> m ()
    at src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs:38:1-53
• In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘throwM’
  In the second argument of ‘maybe’, namely ‘(liftDOM . throwM)’
  In the expression: maybe (return ()) (liftDOM . throwM)

/home/mlitchard/projects/git/reflex-todo/.stack- 
work/downloaded/Vheiln5kqwE0/src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs:42:20: 
error:
• No instance for (Control.Monad.Catch.MonadMask
                     Language.Javascript.JSaddle.Types.JSM)
    arising from a use of ‘bracket’
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘bracket aquire id’
  In the expression: bracket aquire id . const
  In an equation for ‘withEvent’:
      withEvent aquire = bracket aquire id . const

/home/mlitchard/projects/git/reflex-todo/.stack- 
work/downloaded/Vheiln5kqwE0/src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs:45:31: 
error:
• Could not deduce (Control.Monad.Catch.MonadCatch
                      Language.Javascript.JSaddle.Types.JSM)
    arising from an operator section
  from the context: MonadDOM m
    bound by the type signature for:
               send' :: MonadDOM m => XMLHttpRequest -> Maybe JSVal -> m ()
    at src/JSDOM/Custom/XMLHttpRequest.hs:44:1-62
• In the expression: (`onException` abort self)
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘(`onException` abort self)
     $ do { result <- liftIO newEmptyMVar;
            r <- withEvent
                   (onAsync self Generated.error . liftIO
                    $ putMVar result (Just XHRError))
                 $ withEvent
                     (onAsync self abortEvent . liftIO
                      $ putMVar result (Just XHRAborted))
                   $ withEvent (onAsync self load . liftIO $ putMVar result Nothing)
                     $ do { void
                            $ case mbVal of {
                                Nothing -> ...
                                Just val -> ... };
                            liftIO $ takeMVar result };
            throwXHRError r }’
  In the expression:
    liftDOM
    $ (`onException` abort self)
      $ do { result <- liftIO newEmptyMVar;
             r <- withEvent
                    (onAsync self Generated.error . liftIO
                     $ putMVar result (Just XHRError))
                  $ withEvent
                      (onAsync self abortEvent . liftIO
                       $ putMVar result (Just XHRAborted))
                    $ withEvent (onAsync self load . liftIO $ putMVar result Nothing)
                      $ do { void
                             $ case mbVal of {
                                 Nothing -> ...
                                 Just val -> ... };
                             liftIO $ takeMVar result };
             throwXHRError r }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue to the answer came from this project, https://github.com/nomeata/reflex-dom-fragment-shader-canvas.

Specifically, this flag: `package reflex-dom
                     flags: +use-warp -webkit2gtk`.

I have updated the git project above to reflect a working stack.yaml file.